# python list.clear() works in code, not in compiled version

Tags: python, pygame, exe

I have a python game, made in pygame.
the game runs and works ok when run as a python script.
I have compiled the script into an exe file, this did also works fine before I made some changes to the game. Now when launching the .exe an error is thrown:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyg.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "runpy.pyc", line 240, in run_path
  File "runpy.pyc", line 82, in _run_module_code
  File "runpy.pyc", line 72, in _run_code
  File "game.py", line 378, in <module>
    occupied.clear()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

Does anyone have any idea, why my program runs in the IDE but not in the .exe file?

Comment: Did you perhaps use a different version of Python in the two cases?  `list.clear` was added in Python 3.3.

Comment: @BrenBarn Not sure how to check, pretty sure all the code was written in 3.6

Comment: @iHateNodeJS see first if there is a previous post with the same issue, please.

Comment: I used occupied[:] = [] and it works (shrug) I do not even have lower than 3.6 install on any of machines... plain weird I guess

Comment: How did you compile it?

Comment: Using pyg.exe a little bit of software made by someone on the pygame forums